# Output of multiple MySql queries in comma separated format

Tags: mysql, bash, awk

I have to run multiple queries on a table and get the output in a comma separated format. Here is the script I wrote, but it displays the output of each Mysql query line by line.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uuser -p7pas db -e "select number from hits_log where created_at between '2017-04-07 00:00:00' and '2017-04-08 00:00:00'| while read number; do

mysql -uuser -ppas db -e "select number,count(1) as total_hits from hits_log where number='$number' and time between '2017-04-07 00:00:00' and '2017-04-08 00:00:00' ; select count(1) as xxx from hits_log where number_type='some_value' and old_number='$number' and time between '2017-04-07 00:00:00' and '2017-04-08 00:00:00';"
done
```

The output i get is

```
number  total_hits

12345   4

xxxx

0
```

The desired output is

```
number total_hits xxxx

12345 4 0
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You should join the queries to get them together as one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the loop. Just join the two queries.

```
mysql -e "
    SELECT l1.number, COUNT(*) AS total_hits, IFNULL(l2.xxx, 0) AS xxx
    FROM hits_log AS l1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT old_number, COUNT(*) AS xxx
        FROM hits_log
        WHERE number_type='some_value'
        AND time between '2017-04-07 00:00:00' and '2017-04-08 00:00:00'
        GROUP BY old_number) AS l2
    ON l1.number = l2.old_number
    WHERE time between '2017-04-07 00:00:00' and '2017-04-08 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY l1.number"
```

If you really need to do a query for a single `$number`  in a loop, you can still join these two queries to get them on a single line.

```
mysql -e "
    select number,count(1) as total_hits, xxx 
    from hits_log 
    cross join (
        select count(1) as xxx 
        from hits_log 
        where number_type='some_value' 
        and old_number='$number' 
        and time between '2017-04-07 00:00:00' and '2017-04-08 00:00:00'
    ) as x 
where number='$number' 
and time between '2017-04-07 00:00:00' and '2017-04-08 00:00:00' ;"
```

Comment: Thanks, but here what I posted is just a part of a report i am trying to do. I need to join the values from atleast 10 different queries to get the desired output. As of now, I am trying to store the output values to a variable and print each variable comma seperated. Thanks a lot for your help and time :)

Comment: I've added a second query showing how to do it one number at a time in the loop.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot